# Count of unique values in nested dict python

Tags: python, dictionary, iterator, set

I have a dict like:

```
dict = {
    "a": {"Azerbaijan": 20006.0, "Germany": 20016.571428571428},
    "b": {"Chad": 13000.0, "South Africa": 3000000.0},
    "c": {"Chad": 200061.0, "South Africa": 3000000.0}
}
```

And I am trying to get a dict of the counts of the occurrences of each unique country and value.

For example, `{"Chad": 2, "South Africa": 2,..}`,`{"3000000": 2, "13000": 1,..}`

I am using the code below which works but is not very smart, is there a better way to do this without a long iteration cycle, since the actual dict is massive?

```
seencountries = {}
seenvalues = {}

for key, innerdict in dict.iteritems():
    for country, value in innerdict.iteritems():
        if value not in seenvalues.keys():
            seenvalues[value] = 0
        seenvalues[value]+=1
        if country not in seencountries.keys():
            seencountries[country] = 0
        seencountries[country]+=1

print seencountries

print seenvalues
```

Comment: Your countries are *keys*? Since Python dictionaries aren't ordered - how do you know which key to take from each of those dictionaries for the country?

Comment: If it hasn't been seen. The dictionaries contain unique values only, if I understood right?

Comment: They contain unique keys - that much is correct. However - the order of the keys is arbitrary... Or are you counting all the keys and not just countries...? I'm fairly sure for key *a* neither of those keys are countries...

Comment: Edited the question to make clearer.

Comment: Right - so your output is correct, right?

Comment: How is "Pennsylvania Avenue NW" a country, and how did "3000000" make it into the result out of thin air (it's not in the input)?

Comment: Your example is confusing since there are non country names in the example, such as `"Pennsylvania Avenue NW"`. Are these to be counted or filtered out?

Comment: Leave it, sorry, bad example, edited the source data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter
seen_countries = Counter()
seen_values = Counter()
for data in your_dicts.itervalues():
    seen_countries += Counter(data.keys())
    seen_values += Counter(data.values())
```